# Как посчитать количество стран в столбце таблицы из Excel файла?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel

Есть Excel файл, в нем сокращенно в столбец написаны страны:

```
CA
US
US
...
```

Как вывести файл Excel, в котором будет написано в первом столбце количество, а во втором сокращенное наименование с этой страны?

---

Пример [файла с днными](https://my-files.ru/x6clrs/Task.xlsx). Там на третьем листе задание, что нужно. Если бы кто-то хотя бы описали схему, по которой действовать, как там с циклами хоть примерно.

Comment: Что сделали сами? приведите пример кода, который у вас не работает.

Comment: Да толком ничего, я в питоне 0( как и программировании

Comment: import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('./Task 2.xlsx')
w1 = wb["installs"]
w2 = wb["purchases"]
city = w1['B']
city_set=set(city)
row_number_1 = w1.max_row
row_number_2 = w2.max_row
ps=[]
unswer = []
p=1
for i in range(0,5):
     j=1
     while city[j].value == city[1+j].value:
          j=j+1
          p+=1
     ps.append(p)
print(ps)

Comment: @DenisSybin, можете выложить пример Excel на какой-нибудь файлообменник?

Comment: А можно куда нить в личку, а то не мое,просили разобраться, вдруг будут ругаться)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант с использованием модуля [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html):

```
import pandas as pd   # pip install pandas

input_fn = r'C:\download\Task.xlsx'
output_fn = r'c:\temp\result.xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(input_fn, header=None, skiprows=[156],
                   names=['device_id', 'country', 'install_time'])

# расчет количества строк по странам и запись в Excel
(df.groupby('country')
   .size()
   .reset_index(name='count')
   .to_execl(output_fn))
```

Comment: Ты просто бог, спасибо. А может полностью сделаешь?) Ато я вообще тупой

Comment: @DenisSybin, SO работает немного по-другому ;) Здесь принято задавать один технический вопрос, с которым возникли затруднения. Это может оказаться полезным и тем, кто попадет на этот вопрос из поисковиков. Задавать сразу несколько вопросов в рамках одного SO вопроса или решать целые задания здесь не принято - врядли это сможет помочь ещё кому-нибудь... Поэтому советую разбить вашу задачу на этапы и постепенно их решать. Если возникнут вопросы на каком-нибудь этапе - задайте новый SO вопрос. Также считается хорошим тоном указывать в вопросе попытки решения, даже если код нерабочий/некрасивый

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Удачи! :)